# We've so been there

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does "We've so been there" mean?

We've so been there: On the other side of a table from someone chewing with their mouth open. Wide open.

Answer (score 2):

That little sentence contains two modern elements.  "We've been there" means "We've been in that situation" or "That's a familiar scenario."  The "so" is an intensifier, now much used by young Americans and Brits, as in "I'm SO going to get drunk", or "I'm SO over him."  The "so" is always emphasized in this structure, by the way: "We've SO been there."